# How to Create Own Search Results for each variation Site in my site collection

Tags: search

I have 2 variation sites in my site collection for English and Arabic and looking for a solution to create own search results based on query to fetch results in Lists and (basic)Aspx Pages.

Search box and routing to results.aspx page after any search inputs. However I am confused about how to generate search results and display as webpart in results.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making two new custom *Result Sources* which can be added to your default SP search from *Search Settings*. Using *Query Transformations* such as `{searchTerms} site:http://yoursite.com/arabic/` & `http://yoursite.com/english/` you could specify where to search the items, assuming they have classifying (managed) paths.

There's a [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2012/10/09/build-a-specialized-search-experience-in-minutes-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx) which can be used with little customization to give you the results.